# How should I post a form in React to an API?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am trying to POST some data from a React form to an API. To do this, I have created two seperate components, which can be found beneath. Each time I hit the submit button, I get an error "onSubmit is not defined" or "onValid is not a function". I tried to replace `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(album)}>` by `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>` or `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>` but that did not work out either. What am I doing wrong?

createAlbum.js

```
import AlbumForm from "./AlbumForm";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const endpoint = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/album/`;

function CreateAlbum(){
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const handleSubmit =  (newAlbum) => {
        
        const request = fetch(endpoint, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(newAlbum),
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
        });
   
        request.then((response) => {
            if(!response.ok) {
                console.error(response.statusText);
            } else {
                navigate("/");
            }
        })
    };

    return(
            <AlbumForm  />
    );
}
export default CreateAlbum;
```

AlbumForm.js

```
import { Card, CardContent, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CreateAlbum from "./createAlbum";

function AlbumForm(album){

    const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm({
        defaultValues: album
            ? album
            : {
                name: "",
                artist: "",
                imageUrl: "",
            },
        });

    return(
        
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(album)}>
            <Card>
                <CardContent>
                    <Controller
                        name="name"
                        control={control}
                        rules={{ required: true }}
                        render={({ field }) => (
                            <TextField
                                label="name"
                                variant="outlined"
                                {...field}
                                margin="normal"
                                fullWidth
                            />
                        )}
                        margin="normal"
                    />
                    
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
            <button type="submit" >submit</button>
            </form>
    )
}

export default AlbumForm;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass submit function in argument of handleSubmit of react hook form.
currently you're calling api function from parent component and not passing down to child. that is the reason it is giving error